# Kiel nomi aron da apartamentoj?

Tags: single-word-requests

Kiu vorto estas la plej bona por tiaj altaj konstruaĵoj plenaj de loĝejoj? Domego estas tro ĝenerala, kaj ĉielskrapanto pli specifa. Ĉu turdomo estus akceptebla? Aŭ simple apartamentaro?

Comment: En la angla, ni havas konstruaĵojn nomitajn "condominiums", sed mi ne povas trovi tiun vorton en iu ajn reta esperanta vortaro. Kutime, la loĝejoj ene de tiuj "condominiums" estas altkvalitaj kaj multekostaj. Mi nun esperas, ke iu havas respondon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tio estas *(multetaĝa) **apartamentaro***. Se tiu vorto ŝajnas tro longa, uzu *turo* aŭ *domturo* (PIV) aŭ ***loĝturo***.

Mi preferas rezervi *domo* por loĝejo sen tutpublika interna parto. Do laŭ mi *loĝdomo* estas domo, origine konstruita por unu familio, en kiu ĉambroj estas luataj al fremduloj. Tamen, aliaj esperantistoj ne dividas tiun opinion kaj ofte uzas *turdomo* ktp por *apartamentaro*.